# How to add an extra field to a Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

So I'm working on an admin page. I'm registering the form with `admin.site.register`. And I want to add an extra field to the form, which will let me populate a `TextField` with a file contents.

Therefore I need to add an extra `FileInput` to upload the file and populate the `TextField` with its contents. I am trying this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_field = forms.FileInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

but the field is not showing. Any ideas?
Also I have no clue where to access the file contents and populate the `TextField` with that before saving the model.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was in this line:

```
extra_field = forms.FileInput()
```

I solved the problem changing the line to:

```
extra_field = forms.FileField()
```

Thanks to all willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in the constructor.

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['extra_field'] = forms.FileInput()
```

And since you are using the django admin, you need to change the form [in the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) too.

Comment: I am new to Django. Where should I add it in the admin? I tried in the `fields`  attribute of the `ModelAdmin` but I got an error.

Comment: Clink on the link in my post, the documentation explains it, you need to override the default admin form. You can either change the form attribute of your admin class or override the [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method.

Comment: I already have this `form = PersonForm` in the `PersonAdmin` which is a subclass of `admin.ModelAdmin`.

Comment: I am also assigning the following attributes of the `ModelAdmin`: search_fields, list_display, fields, readonly_fields, actions, ordering, list_filter. Could any of those assignments be the cause of this?

Comment: Hmm I guess `fields` and/or `readonly_fields` could cause some interfering with your form. Just for the sake of debugging remove anything extra customization from your admin to see if something is not causing the issue.  Sometimes there could be caching, so make sure you refresh the page with ctrl+shift+R. And finally, make sure that your code is actually being executed, just add `assert False` in the constructor and see if its gonna crash.

Comment: I commented all, not working. And the constructor is executing, nice trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is ok according to the documentation, read note here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

To register it in the admin you should add something like this to your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import PersonForm

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = PersonForm
```

Example from here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-custom-validation

EDIT: it is necessary to  actually register custom ModelAdmin, there are two equivalent ways: using decorator, as in the example above, or use `admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)`.

Documentation for ModelAdmin registration - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator
Registration source code - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L85

Answer (score 0):

Register the model in admin as

```
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

where UserProfile is a OnetoOnemodel that extends django's builtin User Model then after every changes in models run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I already registered the form and the model. Furthermore, I am not changing the model, just the model form. Do I need to apply migrations?